# How to render LaTeX in local Gorilla worksheet

Tags: clojure

I am trying to embed LaTeX formulas inside Markdown cell in a locally running Gorilla worksheet. For example, the following Markdown text should render an inline formula and a standalone formula:

```
This is an inline formula, @@\sin(x)@@, and this is on its own line:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^2(x) \textrm{d}x$$
```

However, when I run Gorilla locally (using `lein gorilla`) what I see is the raw code. Markdown itself is rendered absolutely fine. On the other hand, when pushing the worksheet to GitHub and using an [online viewer](http://gorilla-repl.org/viewer.html) LaTeX formulas are rendered as expected.

[Gorilla's documentation](http://gorilla-repl.org/start.html) is saying the following, which I'm not sure I fully understand:

> **Note**: currently you will need to be online in order for LaTeX to render properly.

What I thought is that it means that I have to have a network connection while trying to render LaTeX, but, if this is indeed the meaning, than I do not understand why it is not working. Another meaning I could think about is that currently LaTeX can only be rendered with the online viewer, but this interpretation dose not make much sense to me.

Any ideas? Thanks to any one pointing me to the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help I have found the solution to this problem—I was using an outdated version of `lein-gorilla` plugin. With version 0.5.3 LaTeX is rendered just fine[1]. The exact plugins line in `project.clj` should be similar to

```
:plugins [[org.clojars.benfb/lein-gorilla "0.5.3"]]
```

Also, it seems I was not aware that I could use the `app-gorilla` template for creating gorilla projects (I was using `lein new app` and then manually edited `project.clj` to add the plugins line). The command

```
$ lein new gorilla-app <project-name>
```

generates a `project.clj` file with the right version of the `lein-gorilla` plugin already in the file.

I guess this is the right way for creating *gorilla* apps, and that it ensures that the plugin will always be up to date.

[1] Some very specific LaTeX formulas seems to have rendering problems, but it needs some more testing and maybe a separate question.